# One to many relationship LINQ update query

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, ef-core-3.0

I've a one-to-many / many-to-many relationship b/w `UserProfile` & `AddressMaster` through intermediate table `UserAddress`.

```
public class UserProfile
{
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserAddress> UserAddress{ get; set; }
}
```

```
public class AddressMaster
{
        public string AddrID{ get; set; }
        public string AddressLine1{ get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserAddress> UserAddress{ get; set; }
        public TheatreLocation TheatreLocation { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class UserAddress
    {
        public Guid UserID { get; set; }
        public Guid AddressID { get; set; }
        public UserProfile UserProfile{ get; set; }
        public AddressMaster AddressMaster { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I am trying to enter data from API through JSON:

```
{
    "Name": "Neo",            
    "address": 
        {
            "addressLine1": "House not"            
        }
    
}
```

For this I've a DTO to take these params. Below is my controller code.

```
public async Task<Guid> Handle(CreateUserCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
        {                           
            var userEntity = new UserProfile
            {                   
                Name = request.Name,                         
            };
            _context.UserProfile.Add(userEntity);
            
            AddressMaster addressMaster = request.Address;
            
            _context.AddressMaster.Add(addressMaster);

            UserAddresses userAddresses = new UserAddresses 
            {
                AddressID = addressMaster.AddressID,
                UserID = userEntity.UserID
            };
            _context.UserAddresses.Add(userAddresses);                                                        

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

            return userEntity.UserID;
        }
```

I am trying to store data individually into respective tables and then tried to map it to the intermediate table. I am not quiet sure thats right way, but data is getting stored in the db though.

Thanks :)

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Do you want to JSON that represents(can be deserialized) those 3 objects?

Comment: The json is received at the controller and my dto gets the data. I want to save the data into the tables from there. `UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile {Name = requestDto.Name}` similarly i get address too. Dont know the linq to save data to the 3 tables involved.

Comment: What are the values of `addressMaster.AddressID` and `userEntity.UserID` when you assign them to `new UserAddresses`?

Comment: I recommend you read [Ultimate Asp.Net Core 3 Web API](https://code-maze.com/ultimate-aspnet-core-3-web-api/) book. This book is very effective. I think this is what you need. I'm not the book advertiser, just a reader.

Comment: @GertArnold its a guid. Its not null.

Comment: @MohammadBarbast will do :) Thank you

Comment: Show some samle values. It's not interesting what they're *not* :)

Comment: C727691F-6C4A-4B7B-B8E6-08D82647334D
:P

Comment: Hi, @Neo, From your json data, I only can see one "address":  {  "addressLine1":"House not"  } in one user. So it's a One-to-One relationship.

Comment: Typical One-to-One relationship.(user:id,name,address). If you juse need One-to-One, your models are too complicated and UserAddress is used for Many-to-Many. Here is the question : What you real needs for User and Address?

Comment: Here is a good guide about the different types of relationships between lists of entities and provides examples. https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/218734758-A-beginner-s-guide-to-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like since there has not been any answer and after looking up some examples, I  figured the answer in my question itself is the right way to proceed.

Consider the records you want to enter:
`AddressMaster` <---> `UserAddress` <---> `UserProfile`

Provided the entity configuration is already configured using fluent API (many-to-many requires to configure fluent API for now) mapping `AddressID` and `UserID` as Foreign key to the UserAddress table.

Now you individually map the respective data into both the `AddressMaster` and `UserProfile` tables and add it to the context.

```
            var userEntity = new UserProfile
            {                   
                Name = request.Name,                         
            };
            _context.UserProfile.Add(userEntity);
            
            AddressMaster addressMaster = request.Address;
            
            _context.AddressMaster.Add(addressMaster);
```

Now you map those entered entities to the `UserAddresses` entity and save the changes.